# Access denied S3 bucket behind CloudFront using alternate domain name and custom SSL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, boto3

Currently we are serving files from S3 using presigned urls, however, some places block S3 urls, so we are attempting to redirect this to a custom URL. We have set up a CloudFront distribution to point to the desired S3 bucket. We have set the Alternate Domain Names to the A record we have from a route 53 hosted zone. We have a custom SSL certificate, too, which we use elsewhere, I believe.

When I use botocore `CloudFrontSigner` to create a signed url as depicted in the [boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudfront.html?highlight=cloudfrontsigner#generate-a-signed-url-for-amazon-cloudfront) I get an Authorization Denied response both in requests and from the browser. When I use `curl -s -v <url>` I get `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access denied</Message></Error>`. Looking over the curl response, I see

```
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=Washington; L=Seattle; O=Amazon.com Inc.; CN=*.cloudfront.net
*  start date: Nov 22 00:00:00 2017 GMT
*  expire date: Nov 21 12:00:00 2018 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "dXXXXXXXXXXXXX.cloudfront.net" matched cert's "*.cloudfront.net"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; CN=DigiCert Global CA G2
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
```

which seems to indicate that the connection to the CloudFront via the alternate domain name was successful. My thought was, ah right, I need an OAI to actually do the connecting with S3. So I follow the directions for adding an OAI to CloudFront. I tried again after making sure that the distribution was deployed (and again this morning), but the end result is always "Access Denied".

At the moment I'm at a standstill. I don't understand why I can't create a signed url that works. Can I get some assistance, please?

Answer (score 0):

Aw damn. The expiration time had a timezone bug of all things. Carry on.